# How to draw on QGraphicsView from QMainWindow

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qmainwindow

Current design shown below of QgraphicsView and QMainWindow class is an example of the design I have in a different software.

I had to add scrollbars to the QGraphicsView.
The original software has all mouse events handled in QMainWindow.

Questions: What is the way to draw on QGraphicsView through QMainWindow?

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QGraphicsView):

  def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.darkGray, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        #self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        #self.viewport().setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        print "sdsads"


  def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        item = QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem("")
        item.setPos(ev.x(), ev.y())
        self.scene.addItem(item)

        print "ev.x() ", ev.x()


class CityscapesLabelTool(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        centralwidget = Window()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget) 

        centralwidget.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("exit.png"))



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = CityscapesLabelTool()
GUI.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean of draw, do you want to draw lines while dragging the mouse?

Comment: Sorry, by I meant drawing a points on the screen, drawing polygon on the screen. All this should be done by clicking on the screen. @eyllanesc

Comment: I mean, I understand that every time you press on a point, that point will be part of the polygon, as it is indicated that the polygon should be finished already?

Comment: @eyllanesc I am sorry, but I really don't understand the meaning of this statement. `as it is indicated that the polygon should be finished already`. Actually the part of drawing is already been done in the QMainWindow class. I just need to place the mouse clicks on the GraphicsView class such that the QMainWindow is able to draw whatever it was drawing - this time on graphicsview.

Comment: It is not drawn in QGraphicsView, but only to add items, my question goes in the sense of how you indicate that you want to draw a triangle, a quadrilateral, that is, the number of sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `QGraphicsView` it is normal to add items to the scene, for example in case you want to draw a polygon you must use `QGraphicsPolygonItem`, also if you want to get correct points you must use `QGraphicsScene` instead of `QGraphicsView`.

In the following example you can indicate the polygon points by left clicking and finish the drawing with the right click.

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class GraphicsScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.polygon = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.polygon << ev.scenePos()
            item = QtGui.QGraphicsPolygonItem(self.polygon)
            item.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red))
            item.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red))
            self.addItem(item)
            # or
            # self.addPolygon(self.polygon, QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red), QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red))
            self.polygon = None

        else:
            if self.polygon is None:
                self.polygon = QtGui.QPolygonF()
            self.polygon << ev.scenePos()

class Window(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.scene =GraphicsScene(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 640, 480), self)
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.darkGray, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        #self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        #self.viewport().setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)


class CityscapesLabelTool(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        centralwidget = Window()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget) 

        centralwidget.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("exit.png"))


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = CityscapesLabelTool()
GUI.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

---

You have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), where you are looking for the solution for a solution of the main problem without knowing that it is the correct one, according to what you comment your main problem is to add `QScrollBar` to the `QMainWindow`, and in that element you want to make drawings, so for that it is not necessary to use a `QGraphicsView` but a `QScrollArea`.

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.polygon = None
        self.setFixedSize(640, 480)
        self.pixmap = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        if self.polygon is None:
            self.polygon = QtGui.QPolygon()
        self.polygon << ev.pos()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.darkGray, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0), QtGui.QPixmap("exit.png"))
        if self.polygon is not None:
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.blue)
            painter.drawPolyline(self.polygon)



class CityscapesLabelTool(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()

        scroll.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Dark)
        scroll.setWidget(Window())
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(scroll)



app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = CityscapesLabelTool()
GUI.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But do basically mean that I cannot write that point drawing or anything drawing code in CityscapesLabelTool class?

Comment: Yes, a query: Do you only want to use the QGraphicsView for the QScrollBar?

Comment: Actually I want to add a scrollbar and show the picture inside the scrollbar. If there is any way of achieveing the same which will allow me to let the drawing code be in QMainWindow, then please tell. QGraphicsClass is already there. I added scrollbar to it because that was the only way I thought scrollbar can be added.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl I think that I have another alternative but before trying it I need to understand what you call drawing exactly, you could show me an example of how you draw, do you want to use QPainter?

Comment: drawing here exactly means that the user is allowed to draw as many points as he wants on the screen. As he draws two points a line is automatically drawn between them. Then as he adds points lines are automatically drawn between them forming the shape of a polygon. Later on when he cilcks he the first point, the polygon becomes complete. So, "I" am not supposed to anything. This all work is already done in that software. I am just supposed to add the scrollbar part.

Comment: problem is that all this work of drawing is done in qmainwindow. Please see above comment

Comment: if you only want the scrollbar and you want to draw surely using QPainter you are going astray, in a few moments I will add an example so you can see that there is no need to use QGraphicsView.

Comment: Am very grateful for your patience.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl 
Try to focus on your main objective not on the problems of your possible solutions, check if the example I proposed helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. As I can see the code of drawing has been been shifted to Window class now. This means that on no account I will be able to keep the drawing code in the CityScape class?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl 
QMainWindow is a window class that is used as a container, so the other widgets will be on top of the CityscapesLabelTool covering your drawing, what you do is just move the drawing to Window.

Comment: Yes, but that drawing part here is very huge. I wanted to avoid moving that huge code to other class. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: unfortunately you will have to do it, you had to foresee this before implementing this logic, each widget serves for something, before which comments can not help you at all because you are obsessed with a solution that is not correct, read it is a XY Problem

Comment: I am not obsessed with this solution. My problem is that this code is not mine. It is an opensource software. This single py file has 3016 lines. Thanks much for your help though.

Comment: 3016 lines in a file!!!, sounds and smells like a badly structured project that will not be maintainable, and is suffering the consequences. I recommend you invest a little time in restructuring your project and separating each part of your project, the business logic part and the GUI part

Comment: https://github.com/mcordts/cityscapesScripts/blob/master/cityscapesscripts/annotation/cityscapesLabelTool.py This is that code.